# Ошибка в Joomla 3.1

Tags: веб-программирование, joomla

Ошибка в Joomla 3.1.
Может кто-то сталкивался?
Когда пробую найти и заинсталировать через "Менеджер расширений" созданный мной шаблон, и когда нажимаю "Установить", то выскакивает ошибка

> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in Z:\home\website.joomla\www\libraries\cms\installer\adapter\template.php on line 81"

кто знает, что делать, помогите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Не работать с Joomla!

Comment: гуглили? `Оказывается, достаточно было заменить в файле XML слово instal на extension и все пошло.` это из 1-го джумло-форума.